# Ubuntu doesn't start from USB Pen, does someone have the same Problem with HP Pavilions?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb, freeze

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Tower PC, it's a HP Pavilion TG01-2202ng with an i7 11th Gen, a 3060Ti Nvidia GPU, 16GB Ram, 1TB M.2 SSD, WLAN and Bluetooth on the Mainboard, and so on. The UEFI is AMI F. 10 Update from 07/29/2021, it's the last Update apparently.

Now my problem: I tried a lot of stuff, but my PC doesn't want to boot the Ubuntu image from my USB Pen. I click Ubuntu in the GRUB and than it takes a few seconds until it shows me all my devices listed. After 1-2 minutes, I get the HP Boot Screen and beneath it's the Ubuntu Spinning Wheel (Loading) and than the Ubuntu Logo. After 1 minute it shows me that "error" stated in the picture.

[image]

I already tried to start it in non secure mode, but than it doesn't even try to start Ubuntu it shows me directly the HP Bootlogo and it freezes there.
Does someone know what I can try? I still want to use my Windows partition, cause I need Windows for some work related stuff and for gaming. I already created a second partition for Linux.

Comment: how did you create the ubuntu iso on the pen drive? Normally when booting the pc, you would press `Esc` to get to the boot options and change the first option to the pen drive then `save and exit` to boot from the pen drive from where you can select `install ubuntu`. Please [edit] your question with the additional information accordingly

Comment: @user68186 That was my first thought too, the ISO is alright, did install it on the VM. I tried to USB pens, would be a lot of misfortune if both are faulty.

Comment: @24601 I did use Etcher and one time I tried with Rufus, both give me the same issue. I can enter the GRUB 2.04 and so on, I even can edit the command lines etc. But it doesn't boot Ubuntu to the GUI, it freezes in the Loading Screen HP+Ubuntu Spinning Wheel+ Ubuntu Logo

Comment: For brand new hardware you probably need the latest Ubuntu - 21.10 -.

Comment: @ChanganAuto It is 21.10. Is there something similar to Ubuntu, maybe I can try out that distro.